# html Iframe creates a white background

Tags: html, css

Thanks in Advance. 
I added an iframe of another webpage to my webpage.
My webpage has a covered background.
when you scroll down my webpage the iframe has a huge white block behind it that blocks out my back ground. I need to get rid of the white block or make it transparent.

Example:
https://e-scapeps.com/hiscore/index.php

HTML:

```
<div class="border2">                                   
  <iframe src="https://e-scapeps.com/hiscore/tindex.php" >
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border2 iframe {
  border: none;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 1890px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display:block; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: use min-height instead height. --> .header-1 { min-height: 110vh;}

Comment: added..min-height: 110vh; the white space got smaller but it is still there.

Comment: It creates a white background because your background image is out of bounds, there is nothing left to show. If you set your `body: background-color: black;` it will be black instead, otherwise you need to repeat your background image, or get a bigger one.

Comment: tried what you said by removing the no-repeat and adding : body: background-color: black;  did not seem to work..here is my background css .. background: url('../images/header-images/bg/aged-hero-bg-1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the backgroung image rule at the:

```
<div class="page-holder">
```

The white background comes from this div, so you can move the background rule from:

```
<div id="home" class="header-1 aged">
```

to

```
<div class="page-holder">
```

I've tried this here in dev tools and worked well. Note that in my case I put the main folder in the URL in order to find the image:

```
background: url('../main/images/header-images/bg/aged-hero-bg-1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;"
```

Also remember to remove the rule from the older div.